# IdentityServer - multiple OAuth servers with compatible tokens?

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect, federated-identity

Is it possible to have multiple OAuth servers, in multiple environments, produce and consume tokens that are compatible across all servers?

We have a vendor product that has an inbuilt OAuth server. We wish to perform the OAuth authentication using our existing IdentityServer on premise. We then wish for the access tokens generated via our IdentityServer to be recognised and permitted for access to the vendor product using its inbuilt OAuth.

What would be involved in producing / consuming OAuth tokens across seperate OAuth servers and environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need `Identity Brokering`. Check the documentation of an inbuilt OAuth server and IdentityServer and search for this feature.